# Count on a selected data in column

Tags: crystal-reports-2010, summary

I have column in which the data is like either 'Y' or 'N'. Now I want to put summary field at the end only for 'Y'. i.e. how many 'Y's in the column.

Please help me how can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer in `http://scn.sap.com/thread/3618451` portal:

1) Create a formula with this code:

```
IF {field} = 'Y' then 1
```

2) Go to Insert Summary > Choose the above formula field as the 'Field to Summarize' > Choose 'Sum' > Place the summary on the Report Footer.

Comment: Yeah, well this is the way.